# Why I can not run tex?

Tags: errors, compiling, mac, texshop

I can not run any LaTeX document because of `error: Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`.

Comment: do you have a pdflatex command in /usr/texbin with the right permissions

Answer (score 2):

Did you recently update to El Capitan or Sierra from an older macOS version? Are you trying to run pdflatex through a front end (e.g., TeXShop) or via the Command Line? How old is your TeX Distribution? If it's earlier than TeX Live 2015 (installed via MacTeX-2015) please update to a newer version. Finally, please go to <http://www.tug.org/mactex/sierra.html> to learn more about it and make sure to read the linked `Updating For El Capitan and Sierra` document linked there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I  updated to  Sierra from an older macOS version yesterday. But I updated MacTex to the latest version today. It still can not run.

Comment: Are you using TeXShop? Can you run `which pdflatex` in Terminal and let me know what it returns?

Comment: If I use TexShop. It runs well. But if I use texstudio, it says "Error: Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "title".tex". I don't know how to do with this. Since it was all right before  I update my Mac. What do you mean by run in terminal ?

Comment: Finally, I got it work well by changing the preference according to "http://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf". Thank you very much for you help!